# как добавить функцию инсерт чтобы добавлять данные в базу но в точнем месте(департамент) C#

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   static string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-2JCI7CD;Initial Catalog=CompanyDb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;
                                        TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillDepartments();
    }
    private void FillDepartments()
    {
        SqlConnection dptConnection =  new SqlConnection(); ;



        dptConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        dptConnection.Open();
        string strSQL = "Select * From Departments ORDER BY dpt_ID";
        SqlDataAdapter dAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, dptConnection);
        DataSet dptDS = new DataSet("Departments");
        dAdapt.Fill(dptDS, "Departments");
        cmb_Departments.DisplayMember = "dpt_Name";  
        cmb_Departments.ValueMember = "dpt_ID";
        cmb_Departments.DataSource = dptDS.Tables["Departments"];

        dptConnection.Close();
    }

    private void cmb_Departments_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmb_Departments.SelectedIndex < 0)
            return;
        string dpt_ID = cmb_Departments.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string strSQL = "Select * From Employees Where dpt_ID = " +dpt_ID;




        SqlConnection empConnection = new SqlConnection();
        empConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        empConnection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter dAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, empConnection);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        dAdapt.Fill(table);
        dGrdViewEmployees.DataSource = table;
    }
```

Comment: Вам надо добавить запись в таблицу Departments? В какой момент, по какому событию Вы хотите это сделать? Сейчас из вопроса этого неясно.

Comment: нужно по нажатия на кнопку инсерт  добавилась новый employee который будет связан через ForeignKey  с Department Id

Comment: Ок, Вам надо для начала добавить на форму саму кнопку, затем назначить ей обработчик события Click, если используете визуальный редактор в Visual Studio, можно просто 2 раза кликнуть по кнопке в редакторе, обработчик сгенерируется сам, далее добавить в обработчик необходимую Вам логику.

Comment: спасибо !!!!!!!